# how to avoid race condition when using Scala's Actor

Tags: scala, mongodb, actor, casbah

I am writing a piece of code that would populate a mongoDB collection when the buffer (list) grow to a certain size.

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class PopulateDB extends Actor {
  val buffer = new ListBuffer[DBObject]
  val mongoConn = MongoConnection()
  val mongoCol = mongoConn("casbah_test")("logs")

  def add(info: DBObject = null) {
    if (info != null) buffer += info

    if (buffer.size > 0 && (info == null || buffer.length >= 1000)) {
      mongoCol.insert(buffer.toList)
      buffer.clear
      println("adding a batch")
    }
  }

  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case info: DBObject => add(info)

        case msg if msg == "closeConnection" =>
          println("Close connection")
          add()
          mongoConn.close
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run the following code, scala will occasionally throw a "ConcurrentModificationException" on the "mongoCol.insert(buffer.toList)" line. I am pretty sure it has something to do with "mongoCol.insert". I am wondering if there is anything fundamentally wrong with the code. Or should I use something like the "atomic {...}" from Akka to avoid the issue.

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
PopulateDB@7e859a68: caught java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:373)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:392)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:391)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:113)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:215)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:180)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollectionBase$class.insert(MongoCollection.scala:561)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection.insert(MongoCollection.scala:864)
    at PopulateDB.add(PopulateDB.scala:14)
    at PopulateDB$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PopulateDB.scala:26)
    at PopulateDB$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PopulateDB.scala:25)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:34)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$class.resumeReceiver(Reactor.scala:129)
    at PopulateDB.scala$actors$ReplyReactor$$super$resumeReceiver(PopulateDB.scala:5)
    at scala.actors.ReplyReactor$class.resumeReceiver(ReplyReactor.scala:69)
    at PopulateDB.resumeReceiver(PopulateDB.scala:5)
    at scala.actors.Actor$class.searchMailbox(Actor.scala:478)
    at PopulateDB.searchMailbox(PopulateDB.scala:5)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$startSearch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Reactor.scala:114)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$startSearch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Reactor.scala:114)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinPool.java:611)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? What component is throwing the concurrentmodification exception?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Is there a reason why 'buffer' and 'add' are public? I'd be making them private/protected to start with to make sure they are not accidentally called elsewhere (by non-actor threads).

Comment: I agree. They should be private as well. But in my case, I am sure they are not the cause for the exception

Comment: Just wanted to add to the discussion: I was experiencing the same issue and it was because I was calling com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.RegisterConversionHelpers() in the constructor of my repository. That function should never be executed at the same time a mongo query is as it modifies the encodingHooks hashmap, which is not thread-safe. Removing that call or doing it only once before all mongo calls fixes the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBObject is *not* thread safe; you're sending a DBObject in with your actor message.  It is likely being modified again later which is going to cause that concurrent modification problem.

I would suggest to start with, trying to use `clone()` on the DBObject as it comes into the actor, and put that into your buffer.  It is only a shallow copy but should at least be enough to cause concurrent modification problems on the LinkedHashMap which backs the keys on DBObject ( which is kept ordered, by virtue of the LHM).

I'd try:

```
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case info: DBObject => add(info.clone())

        case msg if msg == "closeConnection" =>
          println("Close connection")
          add()
          mongoConn.close
      }
    }
  }
```

If that doesn't work, look at anywhere else you are modifying the DBObject after it is sent to the Actor.

Comment: seems like clone is not available for DBObject, which is surprising since I thought clone is inherited from AnyRef. I got around using Synchronized{} in the end.

Comment: It isn't available on DBObject, but it is available on BasicDBObject. Unless you've created your own version of DBObject, BasicDBObject is the concrete implementation shipped in the Java driver (and used by Casbah) and has clone() available.

Answer (score 1):

Why `class` below?

```
class PopulateDB extends Actor
```

Do you keep multiple `PupulateDB` actors? I'd expect `object PopulateDB extends Actor`, so that a single actor would concentrate this task.

Aside from that, the problem seems to be inside casbah or mongodb itself.

Comment: The issue appears to be inside the Java driver (Which Casbah wraps).  It looks like something needs to be synchronized and isn't... although I don't know the Scala actors as well as Akka's

Comment: @Brendan Make the vals `private` to ensure they are not in use elsewhere, but it seems that two calls to `mongoCol.insert` at the same time cause the problem. There's nothing actor architecture can do about, except making `PopulateDB` a singleton, to ensure there can't be more than one call at the same time.

Comment: @Brendan Oops, sorry. I thought you were the Derek.

Comment: @DCSobral No worries... I was confused as well and spent some time over the last day looking for a cause (I usually use Akka for actors).  It turns out DBObject isn't threadsafe at ALL... which would cause this.  I was working on an immutable version of DBObject already, and this further highlights the need.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Changing the code to synchronized { mongoCol.insert(temp)  } solves my problem

Comment: I just noticed why that worked: The way your code is written, you're going to keep calling that insert while another is running.  Once the threshold condition is met, each subsequent message will run that block.  

You should definitely use some kind of a lock or latch or even synchronized to ensure that you aren't trying to run that insert repeatedly unnecessarily.